# Php how to convert a date time string in French back to its equivalent in English UTC

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I have this date time string `vendredi 11 février 2022 à 20:19:56 heure normale d’Europe centrale` stored in my database.

Now I'm trying to convert it back to its equivalent in English UTC date time.

In order to process it, I tried `strtotime`:

```php
$datetime = 'vendredi 11 février 2022 à 20:19:56 heure normale d’Europe centrale';

$tsparis = strtotime($datetime . ' Europe/Paris');

var_dump($tsparis);
```

This shows `bool(false)`. How can I parse this string back to a timestamp.

Comment: The error message you've shown has nothing to do with the problem you're describing. It's just saying that you've missed out one of the parameters to the `new \IntlDateFormatter` function - there should be a timezone in between "FULL" and "GREGORIAN". Fixing that won't solve anything though, because `strtotime` has already failed by that point, and `$tsparis` is `false`.

Comment: @IMSoP Yes that's absolutely right! I'll update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IntlDateFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.parse.php) to [parse](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.parse.php) dates from strings as well as format them to strings.

In this case, passing a locale of 'fr_FR', and date and time formats of "full" should be enough:

```
$datetime = 'vendredi 11 février 2022 à 20:19:56 heure normale d’Europe centrale';

$parser = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'fr_FR',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL
);
$tsparis = $parser->parse($datetime);

var_dump($tsparis);
```

Gives `int(1644607196)`; see [online demo](https://3v4l.org/SuZt7)

This gives you a standard Unix timestamp, which you can process using whatever you want to generate a new output.

Comment: Doesn't work with the "ven, 29 Mar 2024 11:16:40 +0100" format in French

Comment: @zeuf There are plenty of of formats it *won't* parse; but that wasn't the question on this page.